# Segmentation Fault - how to debug?

Tags: linux, debugging, segmentation-fault

My application crashed and it printed on the console the below:

> sh[366]: /bin/sh: line 1:   367 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./myapp

My question is what does 367 here indicate?

I am not able to find the core dump file anywhere.
Any clue how do I debug the segmentation fault in such a scenario?

Comment: ulimit returned "unlimited" but not able to find the core dump file.

Comment: Use a debugger?

Comment: @OpenSourceEnthusiast: don't comment your question but edit it. Is your system using `systemd`? Have you tried to run your application under `gdb`? Do you have some [MCVE] (or perhaps an URL for the source code of your application)?

Answer (score 4):

The 367 is a process id (of the program segfaulting). You could run your program under the `gdb` debugger.

Read [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) then the [documentation of `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Consider also using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

> any clue how do I debug the segmentation fault in such a scenario?

If that fault is reproducible, it is quite easy. Run your program under `gdb`

> I am not able to find the core dump file anywhere..

Read carefully [core(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) (and [getrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html); maybe core dumps have been disabled with e.g. some `ulimit` bash builtins). Your system might be configured (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) to dump core in some other ways (e.g. by [systemd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd.1.html), perhaps under `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/`). See perhaps [coredumpctl(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/coredumpctl.1.html) and [systemd-coredump(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/systemd-coredump.8.html) and [coredump.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/coredump.conf.5.html)

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info when compiling your application [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` (of course, improve your code to get no warnings at all).

Answer (score 3):

Normally my firsts steps to debug a segmentation fault are:

1. Compile the application with debug symbols (`-g` option) but leaving in optimization options to avoid altering too much
2. Run the program under `gdb` with `gdb --args ./myprog` followed by `r` at the command prompt

If you're lucky and the program crashes then type `bt` (backtrace) to see in which function it crashed, called from which function and so on up to main (or to thread start).

If possible an even better option is running the executable under `valgrind` to see what is the first detected "bad" behavior it has. In many cases doing bad things like reading or writing outside of an array boundary don't generate an immediate segfault, `valgrid` will show you the first read or write operation on a location you shouldn't have access to (but that can "work" silently when the program is executed normally). The downside of using `valgrind` is that execution is VERY slow because the program basically runs using an emulated processor; it's so slow that it may be impossible to run the program in the intended context (for example because it needs communicating with a device that would timeout).

Another option is to compile the program with the address sanitizer (`-fsanitize=address`). That will add code in the executable itself to check for memory accesses outside boundaries or to freed memory. The advantage is that the execution while still slower than a regular non-instrumented executable is much faster than running the program under `valgrind`.

Answer (score 1):

GDB has an option to debug even with the .exe file if core dump is not available.

```
target exec -- Use an executable file as a target
```

Use it in this way:

```
(gdb) target exec a.exe
```